# why is my page scrolling down a bit when I reload it

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

for some reason when I reload my page it scrolls down a small bit.
the cause is this code but I don't know why.

```
<script>

window.scrollBy({
top: 100,
left: 0,
behavior: 'smooth'
});

</script>
```

does this force a small scroll?
i thought it just helped with links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the mdn docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

`The Window.scrollBy() method scrolls the document in the window by the given amount.`

So yes the top value will make your window scroll 100px